# Hide column only on DocumentSet Level SharePointOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

We have column "**IsKiDoc**" Type : Yes/No, We want to hide this column in default view only at DocumentSet level but inside the Document set we want everyone can see and make changes on that column. Is there any way to show that column only inside the documentset?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for you, try to use Document Set Welcome Page.

First this is the Document library, for example we want to hide the **Multi Line Text** column,:
[image]

Go to the **List Settings>All Documents>Column**, and uncheck the **Multi Line Text** column:
[image]
[image]
After this step we cannot see the **Multi Line Text** column in **the All View**:
[image]

Then create a new view called **DSView**, in this view you can check whatever column you want, in this case check the **Multi Line Text**:
[image]
Then go to **Library Settings>Document Set>Document Set Settings>Welcome Page View, select DSView**:
[image]
[image]
[image]
At last:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, it is not possible to conditionally show or hide columns in a SharePoint view.

Here are some examples of things you can do using column formatting:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting